# PHP Post Parameter Passing Validation When the Value is Empty

Tags: php, html, contacts

I'm having an issue when the posting a selection value for server side validation. When the user does not make a selection, therefore it is still selected on "Select...". It still passes the empty() method, although the value is empty.

```
<?php

// Email Properties
$email_to = "user@domain.com";
$email_subject = "3DMark3t Contact:";
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$select = $_POST['select'];

function formError($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// Make sure all fields are not empty
if(empty($first_name) || empty($last_name) || empty($email) ||
    empty(telephone) || empty($comments) || empty($select)) {
    // Return error
    formError('Please fill in all of the fields.');       
}

// Regex Tests
$error_message = "";

// Expressions
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

if(!preg_match($email_exp, $email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp, $first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp, $last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!empty($error_message)) {
    formError($error_message);
}

$email_message = "3DMark3t Contact: \n";
$email_message .= "First Name: {$first_name} \n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: {$last_name} \n";
$email_message .= "Email: {$email} \n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: {$telephone} \n";
$email_message .= "Select One: {$select} \n";
$email_message .= "Comments: {$comments} \n";

// Create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

header("Location /");
```

HTML:

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="php/html_form_send.php">
    <table width="450px">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="30" size="30">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="30" size="30">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="30" size="30">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="select">Select One *</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <select name="select">
                    <option value="">Select...</option>
                    <option value="3DModels">3DModels</option>
                    <option value="Graphic Design">Graphic Design</option>
                    <option value="Web Design">Web Design</option>
                    <option value="Tutorials">Tutorials</option>
                    <option value="Report">Report</option>
                    <option value="Requests">Requests</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="32.5" rows="6"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
             <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: If you step through your code in a debugger, at what point does it do something unexpected?  Clarify "an error message" and things like that.  On what line of code is it deviating from expected behavior?  What are the states of the relevant objects at the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing if `$_POST['formGender']` is set, but PHP will return `TRUE` for `isset()` on an empty string.  No selection on your form means that `$_POST['formGender'] == ""`, and that is considered to be "set" in the `isset()` check.

Instead test if it is [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.empty.php) which will both verify if the variable is defined like `isset()` and if it has a non-empty value.

```
if(empty($_POST['formGender']))
{
  $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to select your Gender!</li>";
}
```

Also test for `empty()` here instead of `!isset()`

```
 if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
 if(empty($_POST['select']) )
```

**Update**

I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish with this.  But, `3DModels, Graphic Design, etc` will not be part of the `$_POST` array.  They are potential values of `$_POST['select']`. I don't understand what your intent is here.

```
if(empty($_POST['select']) )
{
  $var3dmodels = $_POST['3DModels'];
  $vargraphic_design = $_POST['Graphic Design'];
  $varweb_design = $_POST['Web Design'];
  $vartutorials = $_POST['Tutorials'];
  $varreport = $_POST['Report'];
  $varrequests = $_POST['Requests'];
}
```

### The source of your problem:

I finally see where your error is.  Instead of `$error_message`, you are using `$errorMessage` for `$_POST['select']`:

```
if(empty($_POST['select']))
{
  // Oops...
  $errorMessage .= 'The selection you made does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  // Should be
  $error_message .= 'The selection you made does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
```

You should turn on `error_reporting` and `display_errors` in PHP.ini *for development and testing only.* An uninitialized variable used like `$errorMessage .= ...` would issue a notice, and you'd see the error on screen.  Turn this off for production code.

```
// Report all errors and notices
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: I correct some things above, instead of formGender I put select and I put empty instead of isset but still not getting an error message

Comment: @Zachary1748 See addition above - you also need to make the change in another line.

Comment: Okay I made both the changes but I'm still not getting the error message. It's uploaded on the server so you can look at it at the site its all updated

Comment: @Zachary1748 Relax - I have a family; I'm not here every second of the day :) See update above. You have a typo in the name of `$error_message`.

Comment: I have one more question if you don't mind. How would I go about having the user stay on the same page and have the errors message appear above the text box and if they submitted it correctly it would have the contact form disappear and have my success message appear.

Comment: @Zachary1748 Give your `submit` button a `name='submit'` Then should be something like `if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($error_message)) // display your error` Otherwise display a confirmation and don't show the form.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) ||
     $_POST['formGender'] == '')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about valudating the value of the input fields using javascript/jquery? Then you would be able to return false on submit, if the input fields required are not filled out.

Comment: Client-side validation makes for good UX, but is never a replacement for server-side validation.  If a field isn't required on the server-side, it isn't required at all.